# UITextfield keyboard resign

Tags: iphone, ios

in my uitableview in each cell I'm having uitextfield when user edits the textfield and after pressing any other button on the screen the Keyboard is not resigning. I did the following in textfield delegates

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textfieldInCell = textField;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    textfieldInCell=nil;// this is the ivar i am using for each textfield in cell.
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textfieldInCell=textField;
    // do the process...
    textfieldInCell=nil
}
```

I am also calling the shouldReturn delegate function once the user tapping on any other button but the keyboard is not resigning. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did u set the delegate for ur TextField ? like textfield.delegate =self; then add textfield to cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that you bind the delegate of each textfield that you create with the view controller and add one line of code in textfield did end editing :-

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   // add the following line
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   textfieldInCell=textField;
   // do the process...
    textfieldInCell=nil 

}
```

Comment: thank u i just added the resignFirstResponder code and i have already set the delegte while adding cells and now it works

Answer (score 0):

have you bind delegate of textfield with your controller? or did you check textFieldShouldReturn calling or not?

i think, binding is missing wit view controller in your case.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

add a line in your tableview where you are adding textfield.

```
<YOUR_TEXTFIELD>.delegate = YES;
```

Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 0):

first check that you give the delegate or not and give the delegate to `UITextField` after that when you call the method of button at that time resign this textfield like bellow...

```
-(IBAction)yourButton_Clicked(id)sender{

   [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
   ////your code write here

}
```

Comment: In this way how would you keep track of which text field was being edited because there is a text field in each cell.

Comment: @ChiragBhutani here resign all textfield otherwise fire loop with subviews of all cells and in this just write code that view == [UITextField class] the resign view mate.. right?? :)

Comment: no paras what i have done was i have one ivar for uitextfield in each cell at TextfieldDidBegin assigning and in DidEndEditing i am making it nil and assigniing the delegate for each textfield while adding it into the cell in this way keeping track of which textfield is being edited

Answer (score 0):

you must try to assign tag value to textfield then in should return method you used that tag to hide the keyboard like this (if you assign the tag -1 then)

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.tag==-1){
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     }

}
```